# Navigate variables in Visual code for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, osx-yosemite

I am using visual code for Mac version to write python code for several projects of mine. I have noticed that while in my Linux system when I am using VS code I can navigate to the definitions of variables (functions or classes) by control and clicking of them, however, I found that in mac I can't do such a thing. Is there a way to make it work for mac as well? Is it maybe my version of VS code that does not come with this feature?

Answer (score 1):

There's an extension at the marketplace. It's very complete and very useful. It's called AREPL for python. It allows you to see your variables and they value at real time. It also shows the output that is going to be shown.

To install it, go to the extension downloader and search AREPL. you will see the extension. Once you have installed it, close and reopen vscode. Now, in your code will appear a poorly drawn cat at the top right corner of the code. When you press it, the extension will start working. If you don't have any variable, the extension will show you the changelog, so if you don't see any variables it's because you don't have any.

I hope it will work. Good luck and sorry for my English !

Comment: De hecho, si quieres la respuesta en español me lo dices 

Comment: The only issue is that AREPL does not help at navigating, directly. I have installed it and figure out that now I have an option open selected code in the AREPL session. But it does not navigate to my code definition which is the thing I want to do.

Comment: Mhmmhmh. sorry buddy. Don't know any other extension or configuration. Ask Microsoft devs at the GitHub page. They can help you. Good luck!

Comment: If you want more people applied to this, go to stack overflow. They will help you better than here